# JOIN, select 'string' if not found

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT p.name, p.price, COALESCE(s.size, 'Medium')
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN sizes s ON p.id = s.product
WHERE p.id = 1
```

If a product is not mentioned in `sizes` table, it doesn't select that product?

```
  id      name      price
  1.     cap         50
  2.     glove       75


 id      product                   size
  1.     2                       'small'
  2.     2                       'large'
```

Comment: If product.id doesn't equal 1, it doesn't select that product.

Comment: How can i select that product with default size `medium`?

Comment: Remove `WHERE p.id = 1`

Comment: no, i want the product even if it doesn't have a size. Should i make another query and work it out with php?

Comment: Can you provide the  test data and result which are requires.

Comment: Based on what you've posted, your tables don't directly support the notion of a default size. You can fake it with joins, but you're better off storing data in tables. (As opposed to essentially storing it in a query string.)

Comment: Your query should work as you expect . . . selecting all products in the product table and defaulting the size to "Medium" if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

what about this:

```
     SELECT p.name, p.price, IF( EXISTS(
         SELECT size
         FROM sizes s LEFT JOIN product p ON p.id = s.product
         WHERE p.id = 1
          ), s.size, 'Medium') as siz
    FROM product p
    LEFT JOIN sizes s ON p.id = s.product
    WHERE p.id = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Your query is fine except the `WHERE` condition

```
SELECT p.name, p.price, COALESCE(s.size, 'Medium')
FROM product p
LEFT JOIN sizes s ON p.id = s.product
```

Here is the code at [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fc93/1)
Let me know if meant to achieve something else with the query.

Comment: To whoever marked it down, I know the solution is same as @NestedWeb posted, I just wanted to add a SQL Fiddle and ask if he wants something else to be done.